# Git Clone: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed

Tags: windows, git, github, git-clone

I was cloning my repository in Windows: https://github.com/garvit-joshi/Competitive-Programming

```
Cloning into 'Competitive-Programming'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 124, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (124/124), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (113/113), done.
remote: Total 399 (delta 53), reused 35 (delta 10), pack-reused 275
Receiving objects: 100% (399/399), 130.31 KiB | 357.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (174/174), done.
error: invalid path 'HackerRank/A: Left Rotation.cpp'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

I have tried renaming the file in GitHub and then cloning the repo but No Success.

Comment: Colons are not allowed in file names on windows, because they are used to indicate a drive. You need to rename the file to something without a colon in the name. The same applies to many other files in your repository.

Comment: Thanks !! I will be doing it as soon as possible. Sorry, I barely use Windows and did not know about this.

Comment: How did you fix it Garvit?